# Is there good standard way to simulate Req/Res over Websocket?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm building my app entirely over websocket. While I see benefit of being able to send data to client without having client to request data to me. There are still benefits to req/res type of interaction as you can put all logic together.

Ex:

Take registration. You send data, server sends a OK or ERROR if something is wrong. 
Right there it's three events! DataFromClient, RegistrationFailed, RegistrationSuccess. But with REST I could have made one POST request and handle if else in one function.

It shouldn't be too hard to create a library that allows you do to push notification + Req/Res type of interaction. It'd be even better if routes could be defined like express routes.

Comment: The socket.io library which is built on top of webSocket has a response model built in. You can send a message and supply a callback that will be called when the response to that specific message is sent back. On the other end, it calls a callback with the response. You could build something like this yourself, but it requires adding some sort of unique tag to each message that allows you to see which response belongs to which request so you can match the two of them up (multiple requests and responses can be in flight at the same time so you have to know which one goes with which).

Comment: There is no "standard" way to do this over pure webSocket.  webSocket is not typically used for request/response queries since that works very well in http.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, my concern is that if you have a socket open there is no need to do http requests on top of that. But I admit practically it's easier to use websocket for only live stuff and use REST for rest of communication.

Comment: Yeah, if it's not a high frequency request/response, then it's probably easier to just do it with http and leave the webSocket for push stuff.  If it is a high frequency operation (client sends lots of requests to the server in rapid fashion), then sending and receiving a webSocket packet is more efficient than lots of http requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "standard" way to implement request/response with webSocket.  It is not part of the webSocket standard.  It can certainly be done (more below on this), but there is no "standard" way of doing it.

The socket.io library which is built on top of webSocket has a response option built into any message it sends.

The sender does something like this:

```
socket.emit("msgName", someData, function(data) {
    // data is the "response" to sending this message
    console.log(data);
});
```

The recipient of a message that is expecting a response does something like this to cause the response to be sent:

```
socket.on("msgName", (someData, fn) => {
   // send response
   fn(someOtherData);
});
```

You could implement your own response scheme in webSocket.  You'd have to add to your data format a uniqueID for each request so you could send that same uniqueID back in the response so the receiver would know which response belongs with which request.